# Transpose row to column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, transpose

I have a table like below:

```
Type     PKG_HA_01_ON PKG_HA_03_ON PKG_HA_04_ON PKG_HA_05_ON PKG_HA_06_ON PKG_HA_09_ON
duration  18.6694          60          15.1951     56.2068     13.6808     13.8404
counter    5               0            5             11          2           0
```

The first row is the header. Now, I would like to transpose table into this

```
Machine       Duration Counter 
PKG_HA_01_ON  18.6694  5
PKG_HA_03_ON  60       0
...
```

I have tried unpivot but the result is not desired table.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Has the table only these 2 rows and only those columns? Or is there a common value for joining the duration and counter rows?

Comment: Hi Turo, the table only contains these 2 rows and those columns.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using `cross apply` to unpivot and then aggregation:

```
select machine,
       max(case when type = 'duration' then val end) as duration,
       max(case when type = 'counter' then val end) as counter
from t cross apply
     (values ('PKG_HA_01_ON', PKG_HA_01_ON),
             ('PKG_HA_03_ON', PKG_HA_03_ON),
             ('PKG_HA_04_ON', PKG_HA_04_ON),
             ('PKG_HA_05_ON', PKG_HA_05_ON),
             ('PKG_HA_06_ON', PKG_HA_06_ON),
             ('PKG_HA_09_ON', PKG_HA_09_ON)
    ) v(machine, val)
group by machine;
```

I much, much prefer this over `pivot`/`unpivot`.  Why?  `APPLY` implements a *lateral join*, which is a powerful construct in SQL (and part of the SQL standard albeit with slightly different syntax).  Unpivoting is a nice introduction to this feature.

The pivoting functions are bespoke functions and not part of the standard.  They also do not generalize in any way, being designed for a single purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
create table unpivot_raw(
    [Type]          nvarchar(255)
,   PKG_HA_01_ON    float null   
,   PKG_HA_03_ON    float null   
,   PKG_HA_04_ON    float null   
,   PKG_HA_05_ON    float null    
,   PKG_HA_06_ON    float null    
,   PKG_HA_09_ON    float null    
)


insert into unpivot_raw
select 'duration', 18.6694, 60, 15.1951, 56.2068, 13.6808, 13.8404
union
select 'counter', 5, 0, 5, 11, 2, 0


select
    *
from
(
    select
        [Type]
    ,   vl
    ,   Machine  
    from
        (
            select 
                [Type]       
            ,   PKG_HA_01_ON 
            ,   PKG_HA_03_ON 
            ,   PKG_HA_04_ON 
            ,   PKG_HA_05_ON 
            ,   PKG_HA_06_ON 
            ,   PKG_HA_09_ON  
            from unpivot_raw
        ) p  
    unpivot  
        (
            vl for Machine in   
            (
                PKG_HA_01_ON 
            ,   PKG_HA_03_ON 
            ,   PKG_HA_04_ON 
            ,   PKG_HA_05_ON 
            ,   PKG_HA_06_ON 
            ,   PKG_HA_09_ON  
            )  
        ) unpvt
) base
pivot
(
    max(vl) for [Type] in (duration, counter )
) pvt
```